# Perform Action with two urls to send two images at a time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image, url

I need to send two images using two urls.here hurdle which is struggling me that is i need to get response from first url and i need to use it along with second url.

```
NSString *requestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserId=%@&CategoryId=%@&Continent=%@&Country=%@&City=%@&Gender=%@&ImageName=%@&AgeRange=%@",PassedUserId,CategoryId,continentTextfield.text,countrytextfield.text,citytextfield.text,GenderText.text,imagename,ageTextfield.text];
NSLog(@"%@",requestString);

NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.2.4:98/InsertObjectImage?%@",requestString];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.


NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.2f);
[request addValue:@"image/JPEG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData;
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);
NSLog(@"imageid%@",compareId);
```

here i need to get the imageId and i've to use along with second url.

```
  NSString *requestString1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserId=%@&ImageName=%@&ImageId=%@",PassedUserId,imagename,compareId];
    NSLog(@"secondImage%@",requestString1);

    NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.2.4:98/UserImage.svc/UpdateObjectImage??%@",requestString1];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.


    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.2f);
    [request addValue:@"image/JPEG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData;
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);
```

Comment: Check the answer just use ur request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a Separate Class for uploading the image. Something like

`ImageUploader.h/m`

Implement all your functionalities in the class, and call the function to upload the image in different threads. See below

**`ImageUploader.h`**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ImageUploader : NSObject
-(void)uploadImage:(NSData *)imageData withRequestURL:(NSString *)url;
@end
```

**`ImageUploader.m`**

```
#import "ImageUploader.h"

@implementation ImageUploader
-(void)uploadImage:(NSData *)imageData withRequestURL:(NSString *)url{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.


    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request addValue:@"image/JPEG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData;
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);
    NSLog(@"imageid%@",compareId);

}
@end
```

Then make a call to function

**First Request**

```
NSString *requestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserId=%@&CategoryId=%@&Continent=%@&Country=%@&City=%@&Gender=%@&ImageName=%@&AgeRange=%@",PassedUserId,CategoryId,continentTextfield.text,countrytextfield.text,citytextfield.text,GenderText.text,imagename,ageTextfield.text];

NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.2.4:98/InsertObjectImage?%@",requestString];
ImageUploader *uploader1=[[ImageUploader alloc] init];
[uploader1 uploadImage:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.2f) withRequestURL:url];
```

**Second Request**

```
requestString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserId=%@&ImageName=%@&ImageId=%@",PassedUserId,imagename,compareId];
url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.2.4:98/UserImage.svc/UpdateObjectImage??%@",requestString];

ImageUploader *uploader2=[[ImageUploader alloc] init];
[uploader2 uploadImage:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.2f) withRequestURL:url];
```

Both the above function will get called together. By the way you should do it `Asynchronously`, rather than `Synchronously`.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi @iphonic thanx for your Answer,but I need to use in the Same ViewController

Comment: @user3357097 I have updated the answer to support different urls, yes you can directly use it in ViewController, just #import `ImageUploader.h` and use the `First` and `Second` Request calls I have written

Comment: @user3357097 do you mean you need to call first service and after complate call other service?

Comment: @user3357097 There is no point uploading images one after another, rather you should use queue, but yes if you want to upload images one after another you can certainly approach the `block` way as @sunny described.

Answer (score 0):

Use Block Coding

```
typedef void (^onSuccess)(BOOL success);
```

// use property

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) onSuccess block;
```

// make a call

```
[self uploadFileWithURL:@"First URL" withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        [self uploadFileWithURL:@"Second" withCompletionBlock:nil]
    }
}];
```

// Connection

```
-(void) uploadFileWithURL:(NSURL *)url withCompletionBlock:(onSuccess)completeBlock {

self.block = [completeBlock copy];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] delegate:self];
[connection start];

}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;{
    self.block(TRUE);
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;{
    self.block(FALSE);

}
```